# Background view NSTextField active when adding subview in NSwindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nswindow

**My Requirment:**

Add `subview` to `NSWindow` and It shuld show as transparent view in `NSWindow`.

**My Problem:**

I have added `subview` (`NSView`) to `NSWindow`. It's works fine. But Background window controls (`NSTextField`, `NSButton` and etc ) active when cick the `NSView`. My question is how do inactive background window controlls.

I have using below code for `subview` the `NSView`

```
[[self.window.contentView superview] addSubview:self.SocialMediaPopView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NSWindow should only have one subview, the contentView.  All the rest of your view hierarchy (controls, views, etc) should be subviews of the contentView.  So you should be using something like this instead:

```
[self.window.contentView addSubview:self.SocialMediaPopView];
```

Doing it this way shouldn't result in your controls becoming active when you click on the view.  Make sure your controls are all subviews of self.window.contentView as well.

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine. But i have added subview as NSTableview or NSScrollview above the NSwindow and also added subview the NSview above the NSScrollview. In Such case NSScrollview active (scrolling) when scrolling above the NSView.

Comment: Hi mikepj..Now we have 3 tier.1.NSWindow 2. NSScrollView 3.NSView. My problem is NSScrollview active when scrolling above the NSView. Please help me.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your response.  Is the NSView not scrolling with the scrollview, and you want it to?  If so, your NSView has to be a subview of the scrollview's contentView.